# Debian 7 kernel 3.13.6 - kworker freezes for no reason and takes several processes with it

Tags: linux, debian, freeze

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure this out.  My Linux server will, at random, decide to just hang everything and it is only ONE kworker thread that does it.  First the kworker thread hangs and gets blocked, then other processes that were running under it.  I can find nothing in the logs that gives me any clue as to why.  I have to shut the server off and reboot it.  It's a DL380 G4 by HP.  The CPUs are 64-bit but have no virutalization code.  I'm running 64-bit Linux.  I replaced the kernel thinking that the stock one might have been the culprit, but it's still freezing.  Is there any way I can find out what's going on?  Also, I don't know which kworker it is until it does it, and then nothing responds so I can't execute things like strace and such.